# Hold execution until Dispatcher.BeginInvoke terminates

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have the following code:

```
public override Geometry GetGeometry()
{
    PathGeometry geo = null;

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        geo = diamond.GetGeometry() as PathGeometry;

        TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
        group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(CrossModelProperties.Left, CrossModelProperties.Top));

        if (CrossModelProperties.IsTransformExists)
        {
            group.Children.Add(new RotateTransform() { Angle = CrossModelProperties.Transform.Angle, CenterX = this.GetCenter().X, CenterY = this.GetCenter().Y });
        }

        geo.Transform = group;

        geo.Freeze();

    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send, null);

    return geo;
}
```

How can i pause the execution of this function until the BeginInvoke Terminates while keeping the application message pump running? I don't want to exit the scope of this function so lambda expressions solution would be great.

Comment: Use `await` or Dispatcher.Invoke().

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is explicitly asynchronous.

To get synchronous behavior use Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a WPF multiple UI threads. Using Dispatcher.Invoke makes the application freeze.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dOpe = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( /* your method here */);
dOpe.Completed += (s, e) => { /* callback code here */ };
```

Pause the thread until the callback. You can call the your function in the callback and continue with the thread.

Comment: I can't return a value for the function inside the Completed event.. Sorry

Comment: And second, If i will pause the thread (which is not exactly what i wanted) before the BeginInvoke call it will not get called.